# Github Pull Request: There isn't anything to compare

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull

I have a master branch, and add_db branch for a simple project. I have done all my code edits and pushes on add_db. However, I want to merge all these commits into my master branch. When I try to create a pull request on github, I get an error stating: There isn't anything to compare.

I made sure I have base:master compare:add_db.

What can I do to fix this?

This is the repository for context:
https://github.com/boxcarcoder/Task-List

I saw on another post that I can use git rebase --onto or git cherry-pick but I am unsure of how to use those. I am new to git. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: This should not be. Check: https://github.com/boxcarcoder/Task-List/compare/add_db. Make sure: `base:master compare:add_db` when creating Pull Request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Git commits are linked list of commits with later commit having and branches are pointers to the commit
>   reference of previous commit. C1<-C2<-C3<-C4<-C5

You can create merge request if your child branch originated from parent branch.

```
         master
          |
          v
 C1<-C2<-C3    new_branch
          ^       |
          |       v
          C4<-C5<-C6
```

if you see commit history of both branches, first commit (head commit) for them is different.
So you cannot create a merge request as both branches have started from a different history.

In your case:

```
      master
        |
        v
C1<-C2<-C3

C4<-C5<-C6
         ^
         |
      add_db
```

In your case you can just compare and merge them, as merging them will create a new merge commit and align commit history.

```
master: C1<-C2<-C3
                   \
                   C7(merge commit)
                   /
add_db: C4<-C5<-C6
```

Also make sure you are always creating a new branch from other branch.

Comment: Hi Paritosh, thank you for your response. Your visuals were very helpful to help me understand what is going on. I did a git merge add_db to merge the branches, followed by git pull (git url) master --allow-unrelated-histories to update my local master branch to my remote master branch. Now that my local master branch has the commits of add_db and is up to date with the commits from my remote, I am now able to git push --set-upstream origin master. My github's master branch now has the commits of my add_db. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I gave you a +1 but it's not showing

Answer (score 0):

I did a git merge add_db to merge the branches, followed by git pull (git url) master --allow-unrelated-histories to update my local master branch to my remote master branch. Now that my local master branch has the commits of add_db and is up to date with the commits from my remote, I am now able to git push --set-upstream origin master. My github's master branch now has the commits of my add_db.

Essentially, I had to do a merge, pull, then push to update the master branch in my remote in github.